# iOS build from phonegap from windows platform

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I have a working phonegap project on windows platform and I can built apk for android. I need build for iOS, but I don't have a Mac. How do I produce the build entirely from windows? Please guide me with things I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Developing for iOS requires xcode.  Xcode requires a Mac or at least OSX.  Installing OSX on a non-Mac is prohibited.